# How to compare two tables in SSIS? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am creating an SSIS package that will compare two tables and then insert data in another table.

Which tool shall I use for that? I tried to use "Conditional Split" but it looks like it only takes one table as input and not two.

These are my tables:

**TABLE1**

ID
Status

**TABLE2**

ID
Status

**TABLE3**

ID
STatus

I want to compare STATUS field in both tables. If Status in TABLE1 is "Pending" and in TABLE2 is "Open" then insert this record in TABLE3.

Comment: How large are your tables?

Comment: Very small. Less than 1000 records in TABLE1 and TABLE2 each.

Comment: Merge Join component is probably a good option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do it by using `Execute SQL Task` tool and writing the following query in it.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (ID, Status) 
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1, TABLE2 t2 
WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.status = 'Pending' and t2.status = 'Open'
```

Comment: You don't even need SSIS for this. You can crate a SQL Agent Job and create a step of type `Transact-SQL Script (T-SQL)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Very helpful as I didn't know about this. But in my case I am also doing some other operations before I run this query so I have to use SSIS.

Comment: Without extending this discussion too far.... you can probably also do those in a SQL Agent Job. But whatever you're most comfortable with. SSIS certainly looks better.

Answer (score 14):

If your tables are not large you can use a `Lookup` transformation with Full Cache, but I wouldn't recommend it because if your tables grow you will run into problems. I know I did.

I would recommend `Merge Join` transformation. Your setup will include following:

- two data sources, one table each
- two `Sort` transformations, as `Merge Join` transformation needs sorted input; I guess you need to match records using ID, so this would be a sort criteria
- one `Merge Join` transformation to connect both (left and right) data flows
- one `Conditional Split` transformation to detect if there are correct statuses in your tables
- any additionally needed transformation (e.g. `Derived Column` to introduce data you have to insert to your destination table)
- one data destination to insert into destination table

[This should help](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorgepc/archive/2010/12/07/synchronize-two-tables-using-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-part-i-of-ii.aspx), as the article explains the almost exact problem/solution.

Answer (score 4):

i think so this is what you are looking for.?

In your case if both the tables are Sql tables then follow the steps below

1. Drag dataflow task
2. Edit dataflow task add Oledb source and in sql command paste the below **sql 
   code**
3. add oledb destination and map the columns with table3

**sql code**

```
select b.id,b.status
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.id = b.id
where a.status = 'Pending' and b.status = 'open'
```

I think this will work for you.