# How can we draw table with SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Is there a way we can take data from a database or a csv file and put it on a "nice" table? Like the tables we can draw in Word for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could import it into a nasty table (i.e. a database table) and then represent that in a nice table in SQL Server Reporting Services.

Comment: You forgot to close you `</sarcasm>` tag there

Comment: I've never used SSRS, is it something simple? Easy to use?

Comment: I'll tag the question as answered. I'll try to find documentation on SSRS. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You could export the data to a .csv file and than create a form letter with Microsoft Word and put the information in the table wanted.

See tutorial: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/create-a-mail-merge-letter-in-word-2013.html

Comment: or do you want to draw a table in SSIS itself? Meaning a GUI instead of using SQL?

Comment: Thanks for your answer desperado, and yes I would like to draw the table in SSIS itself. I receive data from a company and I compare it with ours to put the results in a csv file. I would like to be able to present this in a nicer way but to do it automatically.

Comment: So you want to compare your existing data with the data you receive from the company in SSIS and all this automacically? Would an option be to execute an SQL script which inserts the companys data in a table and than compares it to the existing table? Kinda like explained in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089259/how-to-compare-two-tables-in-ssis-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

you can use excel destination in an SSIS data flow:

[image]